# unable to move fabricjs object

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
canvas.selection = false;
var circle = new fabric.Circle({
    left: 150,
    top: 150,
    radius: 50,
    originX: 'center',
    originY: 'center',
    selectable: false
});
canvas.add(circle);
circle.on('mousedown',function(){
 console.log('down')
 circle.set({
  selectable: true
 })
 canvas.renderAll();
})
circle.on('mouseout',function(){
 console.log('out')
  circle.set({
  selectable: false
 })
 canvas.renderAll();
})
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 2px dotted green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.16/fabric.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

I want to make object `selectable` on mouse down, and on mouse out i want to make `not selectable`. If I click inside and dragging its not moving. But if i click inside more than two times, its working. But I want to make this work clicking once. How to achieve the same?

--Update--

As suggested by @AndreaBogazzi, it will work for mouesmove in desktop, but the same won't work for touch devices as only touch start will work if I touch on object.

Answer (score 2):

Just remove controls and borders to make it only draggable

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
canvas.selection = false;
var circle = new fabric.Circle({
  left: 150,
  top: 150,
  radius: 50,
  originX: 'center',
  originY: 'center',
  selectable: true,
  hasControls: false,
  hasBorders: false
});
canvas.add(circle);
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 2px dotted green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.16/fabric.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

Comment: My scenario is i want to make draggable in some part of circle, and not draggable in rest. I achieved that. But the problem is if i click inside that more than once then it makes selectable,and then move. not on click once. Thats what i reflected in snippet.

Answer (score 1):

This can't be done in fabricjs.
The mouse down event is fired AFTER The selection logic is already executed.

What you can do is making it selectable on `mouseover`

If this works for you, it would equal to an object to be always selectable unless you are running custom logic in your mousedown ( or mouseover ) event to make it selectable under some circumstances.

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
canvas.selection = false;
var circle = new fabric.Circle({
    left: 150,
    top: 150,
    radius: 50,
    originX: 'center',
    originY: 'center',
    selectable: false
});
canvas.add(circle);
circle.on('mouseover',function(){
 console.log('over')
 circle.set({
  selectable: true
 })
 canvas.renderAll();
})
circle.on('mouseout',function(){
 console.log('out')
  circle.set({
  selectable: false
 })
 canvas.renderAll();
})
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 2px dotted green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.16/fabric.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

Comment: the scenario is , on touch device , if i tocuh that object it making object selectable, but not able to move. if i touch for second time, then its moving. I am making some part draggable, some not.

Comment: ok please update the answer as this is a missing important detail